# Why is Facebook's Unity SDK Not Logging Events To Analytics?

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

For some reason, I am unable to get the `FB.LogAppEvent` to work inside an android application built with Unity.

Based on the documentation I've read, the code below should work. But it's not producing results inside the analytics dashboard. You'll notice a method that produces an Android toast that confirms activation. This toast does appear on application start. I've tried multiple event types, including custom types from code generated by Facebook's event generator in the event documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/unity
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.LogAppEvent/

```
private void Awake()
{
    if (!FB.IsInitialized)
        FB.Init( () => { OnInit(); } );

    else
        ActivateFacebook();
}

private void OnInit()
{
    if (FB.IsInitialized)
        ActivateFacebook();

    else
        ShowAndroidToastMessage("Failed To Initialize Facebook..");
}

private void ActivateFacebook()
{
    FB.ActivateApp();

    ShowAndroidToastMessage("Facebook Activated..");

    FB.LogAppEvent(AppEventName.ActivatedApp);
}
```

Comment: If you go into Unity and select "Facebook > Edit Settings" you will find an option under "App Event Settings" called "Auto Logging App Events". Make sure that's checked. Now, see if "App Launches" events work automatically. That will at least tell you if your app is talking to Facebook at all.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is in the way you send event

There are two methods for that:

1. LogAppEvent(string logEventName);
2. LogAppEvent(string logEventName, float valueToSum, Dictionary parameters = null);

You are using second method with "valueToSum" = 0, and that indicates there is nothing to sum, so your event probably gets skipped at some point.
You should use the first method
FB.LogAppEvent(AppEventName.ActivatedApp);

Also make sure your analytics is enabled in dashboard.
Do you see any built in analytic events? Feg. App Launches and other Standard events should be visible out of the box.
[image]

Comment: I've tried every iteration of the event. Just a string, the string and a float (like what I posted), a string, float, and parameters via the dictionary. Have you got them to work in the most recent version of Unity? I've encountered enough bugs with Unity that when something like this happens it's usually my first assumption. I'm not sure what else to do aside from attempting a downgrade. I followed the setup documentation thoroughly.. I've read it multiple times. I even added the internet permission to the android manifest just in case.

Comment: Honestly, I just added that float to see what would happen because the documentation said "Required" but I don't think that it is. Even just using `FB.LogAppEvent(AppEventName.ActivatedApp);` does not work.

Comment: My events are not showing either. The default fb_mobile_activate_app is working, by calling FB.ActivateApp();
All other events do not show on analytics.

Answer (score 0):

For me, LogAppEvent(...) successfully works with the Facebook Events Tracker and Analytics when you do a development build with Unity. When I switch to a release build, I then do not get any of the LogAppEvents other than the ActivateApp() notification.

Will update my answer when I get it working with a release build.